# jquery not contains hiding ths too

Tags: jquery, contains

I'm hiding all `TRs` that not contains word. But the jquery is hiding the `THs` too.

How can i fix this?

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#check_box").click(function(){
        $( "tr:not(:contains('Foo'))" ).toggle();
    });
});

<table id="gradient-style" summary="LMS">
            <thead>
                <th scope="col">Тема</th>
                <th scope="col">Дата на създаване</th>
                <th scope="col">Разрешаване на проблема</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody><tr><td><a href="ticket.php?id=19">вдигане на скорост</td><td>21.01.2016</td><td>Неразрешен</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="ticket.php?id=20">задача за стойчо</td><td>21.01.2016</td><td>Неразрешен</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="ticket.php?id=21">Много ни е студено и нямаме дрехи :(</td><td>21.01.2016</td><td>Неразрешен</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="ticket.php?id=273">Прибиране у-ва д-р Хюс</td><td>21.01.2016</td><td>Неразрешен</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="ticket.php?id=275">Прибиране у-ва Шумен</td><td>21.01.2016</td><td>Неразрешен</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="ticket.php?id=290">Прибиране у-ва Договор Черенча</td><td>21.01.2016</td><td>Неразрешен</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="ticket.php?id=291">Прибиране у-ва Договор Лятно</td><td>21.01.2016</td><td>Неразрешен</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="ticket.php?id=371">Лош Сигнал - Велино</td><td>21.01.2016</td><td>Неразрешен</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="ticket.php?id=390">ресетвачка за мътница </td><td>21.01.2016</td><td>Неразрешен</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="ticket.php?id=440">Манастир Царевброд</td><td>21.01.2016</td><td>Неразрешен</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML. Also toggle will not just hide, it also shows. Not clear if this is relevant

Comment: Yes, i'm using checkbox to show/hide them but its hiding my ths too i updated the first post with the html code

Comment: Of course it will. `th`s are children of `tr` too.

Comment: So the foo is in a `a` inside a `td` inside a `tr` then?

Comment: and how can i bypass the ths ?

Comment: Please note all the anchors in your example do not have closing `</a>` inside each `TD` so the HTML is invalid

Comment: Sorted my example below. Had a mistake first time. Just add `:has(td)` to your existing selector. Demo JSFiddle added :)

Comment: @СебастиянЖелязков please, check my **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vmvzdt78/)**

Comment: If you are going to go with a `tbody` answer, please select the one from  @Jai as *the* answer. His was the earliest of those identical answers (exact timestamp is above the name if you hover it) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting all `tr`. Select `tr` under `tbody` like following.

```
$("tbody tr:not(:contains('Foo'))" ).toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use to have a context to filter the trs which in your case is `tbody`:

```
$( "tbody tr:not(:contains('Foo'))" ).toggle();
```

Comment: You got in with the first "`tbody`" answer +1.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, just check your **</a>** enclosure in **td**

Check this fixed **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vmvzdt78/)**

**Javascript:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#check_box").click(function(){
        $("tbody tr:not(:contains('Foo'))").toggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="gradient-style" summary="LMS">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Тема</th>
            <th scope="col">Дата на създаване</th>
            <th scope="col">Разрешаване на проблема</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="ticket.php?id=19">вдигане на скорост</a></td>
        <td>21.01.2016</td>
        <td>Неразрешен</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="ticket.php?id=20">задача за стойчо</a></td>
        <td>21.01.2016</td>
        <td>Неразрешен</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="ticket.php?id=21">Много ни е студено и нямаме дрехи :(</a></td>
        <td>21.01.2016</td>
        <td>Неразрешен</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="ticket.php?id=273">Прибиране у-ва д-р Хюс</a></td>
        <td>21.01.2016</td>
        <td>Неразрешен</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="ticket.php?id=275">Прибиране у-ва Шумен</a></td>
        <td>21.01.2016</td>
        <td>Неразрешен</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="ticket.php?id=290">Прибиране у-ва Договор Черенча</a></td>
        <td>21.01.2016</td>
        <td>Неразрешен</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="ticket.php?id=291">Прибиране у-ва Договор Лятно</a></td>
        <td>21.01.2016</td>
        <td>Неразрешен</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="ticket.php?id=371">Лош Сигнал - Велино</a></td>
        <td>21.01.2016</td>
        <td>Неразрешен</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="ticket.php?id=390">ресетвачка за мътница </a></td>
        <td>21.01.2016</td>
        <td>Неразрешен</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="ticket.php?id=440">Манастир Царевброд</a></td>
        <td>21.01.2016</td>
        <td>Неразрешен</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This still targets the headings. I made it more obvious: https://jsfiddle.net/fh5fgceu/1/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie You are right! I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Yes. Now the same as several other answers. They do all assume that `TH` are correctly placed in a `THEAD` (which is often not the case). But this will now work too.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `:has(td)`

```
$("tr:not(:contains('Foo')):has(td)" ).toggle();
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/0L4fs4jr/3/

### Note:

- Most other working answers suggest targeting `TBODY`, but I commonly find pages where the `TH` are in the `TBODY`. This will work in either case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("tr>td").hide();
    $("tr>td:contains('test')").show();
});
```

try the above piece of code.

Comment: Unfortunately this hides/shows the `TD`s and not the `TR`s :(

Answer (score 0):

> I'm hiding all TRs that not contains word. But the jquery is hiding
>   the THs too.

That is because `th` are children of `tr` too. Although you haven't wrapped your `th` in `tr`, the browser will do it for you trying to correct your mistakes.

One more way (*apart from some other answers*) to do what you want could be to get the parent of the `td`.

```js
$("#chk").on('change', function() {
 $("td:not(:contains('one'))").parent().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="chk">Show/Hide Twos</label>
<hr>
<table>
 <thead><tr><th>two</th><th>two</th></tr></thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>one</td></tr>
  <tr><td>two</td><td>two</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use 
$( "**tbody** tr:not(:contains('Foo'))" ).toggle();

Comment: There are already 2 answers that do this exact same thing. What are you adding?